# Retrieve Unique records SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table UNIQUES like :

```
ID        DESC      DATE         NUMBER        Amount
100       TEST1     01-01-18     1009674       10.20 
100       TEST2     01-02-18     1009674       245.10
100       TEST3     01-03-18     1009942       156.000  
100       TEST4     02-14-18     00042EX       154.6
100       TEST5     04-15-18     00042EX       25.10
100       TEST6     05-20-18     1011055       1564.0
```

And I would like to get the unique records where the Number field has not duplicate or is not repeating.

Result expected:

```
ID      DESC      DATE          NUMBER         AMOUNT
100     TEST3     01-03-18      1009942        156.000 
100     TEST6     05-20-18      1011055        1564.0
```

Query I'm using:

```
SELECT * FROM UNIQUES 
WHERE NUMBER NOT IN (SELECT NUMBER FROM 
UNIQUES GROUP BY NUMBER HAVING COUNT(NUMBER)=1)
```

Any assistance or help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Pretty sure you want to remove the NOT from your NOT IN since you want only those values that have 1 row for NUMBER.

Comment: You are right @SeanLange

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are pretty close

```
SELECT * FROM UNIQUES 
WHERE NUMBER IN (SELECT NUMBER FROM 
UNIQUES GROUP BY NUMBER HAVING COUNT(NUMBER)=1)
```

And you want:

```
ID      DESC      DATE          NUMBER         AMOUNT
100     TEST3     01-03-18      1009942        156.000 
100     TEST6     05-20-18      1011055        1564.0
```

And my answer gives:

[image]

There are several good ways to do this, I'm just going with the simplest based upon the question by just changing it from `NOT IN` to `IN`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `subquery` :

```
select u.*
from uniques u
where not exists (select 1 from uniques u1 where u1.number = u.number and u1.desc <> u.desc);
```

Answer (score 2):

I would just use window functions:

```
select u.*
from (select u.*, count(*) over (partition by number) as cnt
      from uniques u
     ) u
where cnt = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SRC.ID, SRC.DESC, SRC.DATE, SRC.NUMBER, SRC.Amount
FROM UNIQUES AS SRC

INNER JOIN (SELECT NUMBER FROM UNIQUES GROUP BY NUMBER HAVING COUNT(*)=1) AS NonDupe 
ON SRC.Number = NonDupe.Number
```

I would avoid using column names such as DESC, DATE and NUMBER as they occur in the list of SQL and ODBC reserved words.

Comment: Not to mention columns named NUMBER that contain character data. And columns named DATE that contain ambiguous and incomplete date values. There are many bad things going on in the original. Makes me sad.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the `not exists` method, you can `outer join` the table to itself, and check for nulls in the "duplicate" table.

```
select *
from
    uniques u
    left outer join uniques dup
        on (u.NUMBER=dup.NUMBER)
where
    dup.NUMBER is null
```

This works because the left outer join will return everything from the "left" table (aliased to `u` above), and it will return `null` values from the "right" table (aliased to `dup` above) if there is no row found with the `join on` criteria.